# Is possible to use Cortana for in-app voice commands?

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, cortana

Is possible to use Cortana when application is running in Windows Universal Apps?
My use-case is pretty simple - I need to handle situation, when user say: "Open report from {June 2015}" where {June 2015} is placeholder and can contain any date...
I know how to do this when application isn't running and application needs to be launch; but I'm not sure if is possible to do this when app is running...

Comment: I think the [Speech Recognition and Synthesis sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis) covers what you need. You can construct a custom grammar for the sentences you need to recognize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use Cortana when application is running. You app will be activated regardless of its state, so it doesn't make a difference whether your app is running or not, it will be activated anyway. It means that the [OnActivated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.application.onactivated.aspx) method will be called (with VoiceCommand as [ActivationKind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.activation.activationkind.aspx)) when user calls your app by a voice command.

Comment: I'll mark this answer as correct answer, but this isn't match with my use-case; but problem is in question itself, I thought this could be done only by Cortana... Anyway my solution: basically when application goes to MainPage.xaml I'm collecting all reports and creating collection of voice commands (like "open report from {x}", "open from {x}", ...) and then I just create SpeechRecognitionListConstraint with list of created voice commands and add this list constraint to constraints of SpeechRecognizer object.

Comment: @SebastianBusek if the Speech Recognition library uses the same engine that Cortana does, and gets improved over time like Cortana, then there should be no reason to use Cortana when app is running...